# How to hook into application and process startup in windows?

Tags: windows, hook

I am trying to write a program that will hook into application startup and capture the commandline. Don't have an idea where to start as I am pretty green in windows programming.
Would appreciate any help
thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "hook into application startup"? You want your app to be send notification whenever a process starts?

Comment: Please give us some explanation on why you want to try such a thing. We may suggest easier aproaches and maybe alternative techniques. And it will also help clearing suspicion may arise because hooking techniques are often used for malicious purpouses, and we don't really want to help then. Anyway, get your feet really wet in windows system programming first, before trying to write a system hook, it's not an introductory type of task.

Comment: Far from malicious- if my purpose was so I'd have much more easier ways to accomplish that than ask a very basic question here on stack overflow! But to answer your question- I want to be able to track all things that I do on my computer, I tend to work deeply in something and then forget about if for months. I want to create a giant database of my activities which I can search and get to and want to do this least intrusively. So a service which watches my actions would be useful...  I use XP and windows 7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't mention your prefered programming language, so I'll use C# for example snippets.

You can start a process and capture/write into its standard IO streams.

The following snippet, opens a process and captures its **StdOut** stream:

```
using (var process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(FileName = @"yourExecutablePath", UseShellExecute = false, RedirectStandardOutput = true)))
    using (var stdout = process.StandardOutput)
        Console.WriteLine(stdout.ReadToEnd());
```

---

**EDIT 1**

Looks like you want to hook Windows APIs like **CreateProcess**.

One way to do so is to write a kernel driver and use hooking techniques such as SSTD patching. But writing a kernel driver IMO is cumbersome.

In some cases you can use user-level hooks. There are a few libraries that might help you with that, including: **EasyHook**, **Deviare**, and **MS Detour**.

---

**EDIT 2**

You can also use **WMI** as [`@David Heffernan`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan) suggested but it will only notify you **AFTER** the process gets started (as opposed to hooking, which allows you to run some arbitrary code **BEFORE** the hooked function gets called and/or override the function call):

```
using System.Management;

// Run this in another thread and make sure the event watcher gets disposed before exit

var start = new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace"));    

start.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(delegate (object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e) {
    console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Command Line: {1}", e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value, e.NewEvent.Properties["Commandline"].Value);
});

start.Start()
```

Comment: I think WMI can send you notifications.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, you can create a query in WMI and get notified when a process is started / stopped and get the process command-line arguments, but it's not usable for hooking tasks.

Comment: Wmi sounds interesting. You are correct in that I guess all that it boils down to is I want to get notified of process start, actually more specifically, processes that user starts actively.  I suppose windows itself sends a WMI event when CreateProcess API is invoked . How would I accomplish that ?

Comment: @treefrog Edited the answer. Try it.

Comment: thanks much! boo to the person who down-voted the question. maybe a troll.

Comment: plus one for the most elegantly formed understatement "But writing a kernel driver IMO is cumbersome." :)