# what event will be fired when start an exe program on windows 7?

Tags: c#, winapi, c#-4.0, windows-7, c#-3.0

On windows 7, when an exe program is started, what event is fired? How to hook-up this event in code to capture the startup?

.exe could be any program runable on windows 7, for example, WPF app or legacy app for windows XP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157548/how-to-hook-into-application-and-process-startup-in-windows

Comment: If you could explain why you want this information, or how you plan to use it (i.e. your overall goal), we may be able to provide decent answers, or steer you in a better direction

Comment: I want to capture an startup in a service so that I can log or stop it if the app not in my list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Process Monitor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986249/c-sharp-process-monitor)

Comment: Thank you. Try it and looks like working.

Answer (score 0):

There are process create hooks which can be handled in kernel mode.  Anything reported to user-mode will be after the fact (event log entries, WMI events).