# How to create a service that monitors for a program to start?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, wcf, service

I'm trying to create a service that will wait for a program to be run.

Say I run iTunes.exe, my service will then do something like show a message box that will say "iTunes.exe has started".

Comment: did you write any code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8157548/34397

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can achieve this is to periodically get the list of processes and check weather the process you wait for is already started:

```
while(Process.GetProcesses().All(p=>p.ProcessName.ToLower() != "itunes.exe"){
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
//Do Something!
```

**Edit:**

A better solution would be to query Windows Management Instrumentation service and watch for new processes:

```
// Run this in another thread and make sure you dispose the event watcher before exit
var start = new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace"));    

start.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(delegate (object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Command Line: {1}", e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value, e.NewEvent.Properties["Commandline"].Value);
});

start.Start();
```

Comment: That's a very bad approach.

Comment: A bad yet the only solution.

Comment: Yes, sorry my bad. I forgot about WMI requests :)