# Code to open application based on other processes

Tags: c#, .net

I developed one application for my personal use. I want to open/run that application when ever I launches notepad in my system. Is there anyway to run my exe file when ever notepad.exe is ran in my system ?

Comment: have you tried google search or tried anything yet?

Comment: Sounds like the behavior of a virus.

Comment: Check out (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157548/how-to-hook-into-application-and-process-startup-in-windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to create a "bat" file and execute both programs.

add this to your bat file

```
cd "C:\\path\to\your\app"
start /min yourapp.exe
cd "C:\\path\to\notepad"
start notepad.exe
```

Whenever you'll want to run notepad, you'll open it using the bat file. For easier use; point your notepad shortcuts to this bat file.

checkout [this link](http://www.overclock.net/t/88829/how-to-launch-two-or-more-applications-from-one-single-shortcut) for more information

Answer (score 0):

1- Rename notepade.exe file to notepad1.exe or other name.

2- Create a batch file that contains two line:

Notepad1.exe

yourApp.exe

3- save batch file on c:\windows as notepad.bat name.