# How to get the newly opened apps WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there any way to get the newly open apps? I have a function that gets the running apps every 10 seconds, place them on a listbox and sends them to the other window if you click the send button.

What I wanted to happen is to get the newly opened app and send it to the other window. For example:

for the first 10 secs, I have opened notepad and chrome, after clicking send, those two will be sent to the other window. For the next 10 secs, I opened another app which is firefox. So my opened apps are now notepad, chrome and firefox so when I click send, I only want firefox to be sent to the other window so it wouldn't be redundant. Is this even possible?

There's the codes, in case if it brings of any help.

```
private void SendData()
        {
            String processID = "";
            String processName = "";
            String processFileName = "";
            String processPath = "";
            string hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();

            listBox1.BeginUpdate();
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    piis = GetAllProcessInfos();

                    try
                    {
                        processID = piis[i].Id.ToString();
                        processName = piis[i].Name.ToString();
                        processFileName = piis[i].FileName.ToString();
                        processPath = piis[i].Path.ToString();
                        output.Text += "\n\nSENT DATA : \n\t" + processID + "\n\t" + processName + "\n\t" + processFileName + "\n\t" + processPath + "\n";     
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        wait.Abort();
                        output.Text += "Error..... " + ex.StackTrace;

                    }

                    NetworkStream ns = tcpclnt.GetStream();
                    String data = "";
                    data = "--++" + "  " + processID + " " + processPath + " " + processFileName + " " + hostName;
                    if (ns.CanWrite)
                    {
                        byte[] bf = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(data);
                        ns.Write(bf, 0, bf.Length);
                        ns.Flush();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                listBox1.EndUpdate();

            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the Id of previously sent processes in a list and only send the process info of a process if it's id is not in the list.

```
private List<int> listedProcesses = new List<int>();

//...

try
{
    if(!listedProcesses.Contains(piis[i].Id)
    {
        listedProcesses.Add(piis[i].Id);
        processID = piis[i].Id.ToString();
        processName = piis[i].Name.ToString();
        processFileName = piis[i].FileName.ToString();
        processPath = piis[i].Path.ToString();
        output.Text += "\n\nSENT DATA : \n\t" + processID + "\n\t" + processName + "\n\t" + processFileName + "\n\t" + processPath + "\n";     
    }
}

//...
```

Also: when you close processes these two lines will no longer be valid:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    piis = GetAllProcessInfos();
```

Because the number of processes can now be lower than the number of items in the listbox.

To keep them in sync you will also have to remove items from the listbox when processes are closed.

To fix it even more efficient (and easier) you could simply clear the listbox and add a new item for each process returned by GetAllProcessInfos();

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you for the quick response sir. Appreciate it.

Comment: Found an error. Why does it goes on error every time I immediately close an application? Here's the error pointing to the list: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index.

Comment: @helpmeplease - I added to my answer at the bottom

Comment: Thank you sir but I'm quite not sure on how to do it. This is all new to me

Answer (score 0):

Have a hook as described here: [How to hook into application and process startup in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157548/how-to-hook-into-application-and-process-startup-in-windows)

```
using System.Management;

// Run this in another thread and make sure you dispose the event watcher before exit

var start = new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace"));    

start.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(delegate (object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e) {
    console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Command Line: {1}", e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value, e.NewEvent.Properties["Commandline"].Value);
});

start.Start()
```