# Workaround external exception in cmd - c#

Tags: c#, windows, exception, cmd

I have a method that running an EXE file using cmd. This EXE file getting an exception during its initializing, then retrying and starting a process on my system. I cannot edit the EXE file to change its behavior.
when running the code, after the exception, the command line window closed immediately. 
How can I keep the cmd window open till the retry?
Thanks,
Tal.

```
  public void RunJob(Process cmdProcess)
    {                     
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmdProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(form.SortOutputHandler);
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        cmdProcess.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(form.SortOutputHandler);
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/k cd  \"{0}\\BinFolder\"", form.txtLocalRepo);
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";

        cmdProcess.Start();

        StreamWriter cmdStreamWriter = cmdProcess.StandardInput;

         cmdProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();

        cmdStreamWriter.WriteLine("START testing.exe");
    }
```

Comment: You don't have to keep the window open. You can use Process.WaitForExit() to wait for the program and at the same time can receive a WMI event notifying you about the start-up of the backup program (which starts when the executable you had started fails during initialization). You may check the following: (Accepted answer, EDIT 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157548/how-to-hook-into-application-and-process-startup-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Console Application, then you might consider using the new [Async Main](http://pmichaels.net/2017/09/10/async-main-c-7-1/) method.  You could combine this with something like [TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx) so you can flag your app as complete when you're ready, and have it wait until you flag the task as complete.